# How would this be done technically in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to pull data from a SHEET1 to SHEET2 based on product components, somewhat like inventory tracking.

Say on SHEET1 I have added all the components to the corresponding ID of the product.
And now I would want to enter the product ID and in the CELLs of SHEET2 have the data from SHEET1.

Thats 1 way I am trying to have this done:
=IFS(A6=11;'SHEET1'!D2;A6=14;'SHEET1'!D5 )

A question is how to have the D**2** cell number be the content of cell A6

> A6=11;'SHEET1'!D**2**;

Hope this makes sense... Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, if I understand, you want to enter `11` in `A6` and have it automatically change to the value of `D2` from `Sheet1` in `A6`?

Comment: Not exactly.
I want to know if it is possible to change the formula or somehow do this:
=IFS(A6=11;'SHEET1'!D*; (Where the star is I want the value of the cell A6 to be placed)

Comment: okay:  `INDEX('Sheet1'!D:D,A6)` will do it.

Comment: Not exactly what I am trying to ask.
I'm bad at explaining stuff, sadly.

Lets say I have a formula: =A1+B1+C(A3) (So say I have a number 10 in cell A3, and I want it to be put in the formula like this: =A1+B1+C10

Comment: yes and INDEX will do that: `=A1+B1+INDEX(C:C,A3)`

Comment: Amazing! Now I understood how it works.
=IFS(A6=A6,INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,A6))
This is what I was trying to achieve.
Now a second question, basically why I have used the tag of google sheets, would this formula work on there?

Comment: Yes this one will, but there are many that are not cross platform.  As well, even if the formula exists in both, does not mean that they will work the same.  There are more differences than most know.  That is why we ask to specify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDIRECT` to convert a string into a cell reference. So, what you want to do is:

```
=IFS(A6=11;INDIRECT("'SHEET1'!D"&A6)...
```